# Should we sign our release build with distribution or developer identity?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I am in a dilemma.

If I set that to distribution I can't test my application on my own IOS. If I set that to distribution I got this error.

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
```

So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Archive your release builds and then use the Xcode Organizer to distribute them (using the various options from the "Distribute" button), then Xcode will re-sign your builds with your distribution certificates. So you should always sign your builds with developer certificates, and let the Organizer re-sign them with distribution certificates as needed.

Answer (score 1):

When testing the build, sign the app with Developer Certificate. When releasing it for the app store, use the Distribution Certificate for Signing.

You **won't be able to Debug** your app with Distribution profile!